# Cypress - Can't read video from test run results page

Tags: cypress

Checking for failed test cases, I found out that when I try to read the video recording of the test run, I always end up with the error message "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported."

This happens on my linux laptop :

- on Chrome, with or without AdBlockPlus activated
- on a brand new Firefox

This also happens on my Windows 10 laptop :

- on Chrome, with or without AdBlockPlus activated
- on a brand new MS Edge

Steps to reproduce :

1. Visit "latest run" page.
2. Click on a failed test case => the right side pane appears.
3. Click on the "Watch video" link => the modal containing the video appears, and video player displays the error message

Does anyone face the same problem ? Any help appreciated.

Best,

Nicolas